# Node.js - Wait for multiple async calls to finish before continuing in code

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, npm

So basically i have a for loop with an async function in it. Problem is that the program just continues after the loop and i want it to wait until all async functions which were called in the loop are finished before the code continues.

In my code "bar" is a json array with other json arrays in it.

```
function write(bla) { // gets called one after another

  for(var url in bla) {
    asyncFunctionCall(url); // Executed about 50 times, it has to run parallel
  }
  // Wait for all called functions to finish before next stuff happens and
  // write gets called again.

}

for(var foo in bar) {
  // Here i parse the json array "foo" which is in the json array "bar"
  write(foo[bla]); // bla is an array of multiple urls.
}
```

The async function call looks something like this:

```
var request = require('request');

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if(typeof response !== 'undefined') {
    if((response.statusCode >= 400 && response.statusCode <= 451)
    || (response.statusCode >= 500 && response.statusCode <= 511))
      return true;
    return false;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Look into Promises.

Comment: You can't use a synchronous for loop in this case here. Please refer to the library async in npm. Many of it's functions can be used depending upon your use case

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925514/157247) for the edit to the `for(var foo in bar)` loop.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The simplest way here is to use promises, directly or via `async`/`await` syntax. In this case, probably directly.

First, you have to make `asyncFunctionCall` return a promise. It looks like you always return a boolean, so in this case we'll always resolve the promise:

```
function asyncFunctionCall(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if(typeof response !== 'undefined') {
        if((response.statusCode >= 400 && response.statusCode <= 451)
        || (response.statusCode >= 500 && response.statusCode <= 511)) {
          resolve(true);
          return;
        }
      }
      resolve(false);
    });
  });
}
```

Then, build up an array of your promises, and use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to complete. These calls run **in parallel**:

```
function write(bla) { // gets called one after another
  const promises = [];
  for(var url in bla) {
    promises.push(asyncFunctionCall(url)); // Executed about 50 times.
  }
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Then you can build a chain of all of the promises from `write` so they run in series:

```
let p = Promise.resolve();
for (const foo in bar) { // <== Notice `const`
  // See "Edit" below
  p = p.then(() => {
    // Here i parse the json object "foo" in the json array "bar"
    // bla is an array of multiple urls.
    return write(foo[bla]));
  });
}
```

Note that it's important that you use `const` or `let`, not `var`, for `foo` in that loop, because the `then` callback closes over it; see [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for why `const` and `let` make that work.

Each call to `write` will only be made when the previous one's work is done.

Then wait for the whole process to complete:

```
p.then(() => {
  // All done
});
```

You haven't shown anything *using* the booleans from `write`'s requests, but they're available (as an array) as the resolution value of the promise from `write`.

---

The second part of the process, where we're calling `write`, can also be written in an `async` function which may make the logical flow clearer:

```
async function doTheWrites() {
  for (const foo in bar) {
    // Here i parse the json object "foo" in the json array "bar"
    // bla is an array of multiple urls.
    await write(foo[bla]);
  }
}
```

Then the overall process:

```
doTheWrites().then(() => {
  // All done
});
```

...or if this is *also* in an `async` function:

```
await doTheWrites();
```

Comment: Hm now i'm getting an error at asyncFunctionCall() --> "Error: undefined is not a valid uri or options object."

Comment: @Rxchard - That wouldn't relate to the changes above, sounds like a problem with the `url` being passed into it.

Comment: Alright, seems to work now. Thank you very much T.J. :)

Comment: Better yet, you can use `const` over `let` since `foo` isn't being reassigned.

Comment: @ScottRudiger - Quite true. I do that with `for-in` and `for-of` all the time, I wonder why I wrote `let` above. Huh. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Make the functions async and await the calls:

```
async function write(foo) {
   for(const url of foo) {
      await asyncFunctionCall(url);
   }  
}

(async function() {
   for(const foo of bar) {
     await  write(foo);
   }
})()
```

That will execute one request after another. To execute them on parallel use Promise.all:

```
const write = foo => Promise.all(foo.map(asyncFunctionCall));

Promise.all(bar.map(write))
  .then(() => console.log("all done"));
```

Comment: There's also the minor detail that as far as we know, `asyncFunctionCall` doesn't return a promise, as it uses `request` and old-style Node.js callbacks.